# Unable to fetch data from Laravel Eloquent Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

i wanted access the value of `content_type_id` .i tried like `$courseChapters['chapter_content']['content_type_id']` ,  `$courseChapters['content_type_id']` , `$courseChapters[0]['content_type_id']` & `$courseChapters['chapterContent']['content_type_id']`.All these shows the error `ErrorException: Undefined index: content_type_id` . I also tried everything in the `foreach` loop i've commented below. Nothing works. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
/*foreach($courseChapters as $key){
   // $contentTypeId=$key->first(); //Call to a member function first() on int
  //  $contentTypeId=$key->first()->chapter_content; //Call to a member function first() on int
  //  $contentTypeId=$key['chapter_content']['content_type_id']; //error - Illegal string offset
  //  $contentTypeId=$key[0]['content_type_id']; ////error - Illegal string offset
  //  $contentTypeId=$key['content_type_id']; //error - Illegal string offset 'content_type_id' 
  }*/
```

```
$courseChapters = courseChapter::with(['chapterContent' => function ($q) use ($id) { $q->where('course_chapter_id', $id)->select('course_chapter_id','file_id','content_type_id');}])
            ->select('id','courseId', 'chapter_title', 'isExam', 'points')
            ->get()->toArray()[0];
```

### Heading ## `dd($courseChapters);` shows array like given below:

```
array:6 [
  "id" => 4
  "courseId" => 24
  "chapter_title" => "chapter1"
  "isExam" => false
  "points" => 8
  "chapter_content" => array:1 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "course_chapter_id" => 4
      "file_id" => 1
      "content_type_id" => 1
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: chapter_content has multiple records so you did not access as per above.

Comment: @Smithiam so, how can i access it? pls tell me that

Comment: $courseChapters['chapter_content']->pluck('content_type_id')->implode(',');

Comment: @Smithiam this shows the error `Call to a member function pluck() on array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this to access the first

```
echo $courseChapters['chapter_content'][0]['content_type_id'];
```

or like this to access all of them

```
foreach ($courseChapters['chapter_content'] as $chapter) {
    echo $chapter['content_type_id'];
}
```

Comment: What if multiple records in chapter_content array ? This is for first key only

Comment: Just use a foreach. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That's the correct

Comment: i can access the `content_type_id` with ur first method itself. How can i access the  `course_chapter_id`?

Comment: Just use that as a key instead. $courseChapters['chapter_content'][0]['course_chapter_id']

Comment: If this works for you, can you please mark this as the selected answer? Thanks!

Comment: Am checking. i'll do mark if it's useful for me